# nginx location regex /yyyy/mm/dd/

Tags: regex, nginx, location, url-rewriting

I'm trying to pass requests from address **helpme,com/donor/2014/12/07/Name** on the other server.

URL like the: **/donor/2014/12/07/Mike**

need to convert to a query type of: **/donor.php?yyyy=2014&mm=12&dd=07&donor=Name**.

Now i have:

```
location ~* ^/donor/+$ {

  rewrite ^/(.*) /donor.php?yyyy=$1&mm=$2&dd=$3&donor=$4 break;
        proxy_pass         http://164,151,234,168;
        proxy_redirect     off;
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header Host $host;
  proxy_set_header X-Host $host;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
```

Help me please.

Answer (score 1):

The regex for that should be (untested) something like `/donor/(\d{4})/(\d{2})/(\d{2})/(.+)`.

The use of commas (,) instead of periods (.) for the hostname/IP seems wrong, though. As far as I know the same character is used everywhere….